# What does grayed-slashed icon in Google Hangouts mean?

Tags: google-chat

I tried to text a person in Hangouts whose profile icon appears like the image below.

[image]

There is some peculiar info related to this. When I tried to text that person, it showed 'Failed to send... Tap to retry'. I couldn't send any messages. I could see their last seen but with this thumbnail only.

Does it mean the person has deleted the Hangouts account or signed out?

Comment: I'm not using Hangouts so I don't know if it's the same or not, but other Google services (e.g. YouTube) uses the same avatar for deleted accounts. Is there any info when you tap the account, compared to normal users?

Comment: Yes there are some peculiar info related to this. When i tried to text that person it shows 'Failed to send...Tap to retry'.I couldn't send any messages. I could see their last seen but with this thumbnail only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What does the Grayed, slashed-out profile picture mean on hangouts?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507045810/https://support.google.com/hangouts/thread/15145351) from Google Hangouts help says, it could be any of these:

> - Signed out of hangouts or is inactive
> - Account was deleted or suspended.
> - It might also mean the photo was deleted.